# Elegantly change 2011-10-31T16:22:00 to 2011-10-31 in php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, api

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this.
I am running PHP Version 5.2.16.

Up until now I have used a substring.

```
$Date = substr($Date,0,10);
$Date = mysql_real_escape_string($Date);
```

I am scraping this string from an REST Api, so I have no control over its format, and I am not sure if the 'T' in the middle of the string could cause a problem.

Now this does the job simply enough but I was looking to use something more elegant like

```
$Date = Date::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTh:i:s', $Date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

but this just returns the error:
*Fatal error: Class 'Date' not found in...*

Im quite new to php but I am assuming that I require the Date class (Common sense) but how would I implement this class into my script?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
<?php

$Date = strtotime("2011-10-31T16:22:00");

$converted = date("Y-m-d", $Date);

echo ($converted);

?>
```

Look here http://codepad.org/TNIwXDRp

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!! Now the place that I offers the API can change there format to just about anything and strtotime should handle it.

Very versatile yet so simple :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

The class is called `DateTime`

```
$Date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTh:i:s', $Date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

http://php.net/book.datetime

However, because the format is standardized (ISO 8601) it should not surprisingly change, so it should be safe to just split it into date and time yourself

```
list ($date, $time) = explode('T', $string);
```

Comment: I tried: 
$Date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-dTh:i:s', $Date)->format('Y-m-d');
but got:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat()

Any Idea why I am having such issues with DateTime?

Comment: @Beyerz - what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: @MarkBaker - It's right there in the question, PHP/5.2.16. I won't downvote a solution that's otherwise correct but this solution is not suitable since it requires PHP/5.3.

Comment: That's why I make a habit of listing the version of any program I use before asking my question :) but @KingCrunch when I do eventually move onto php5.3+ I will come back to this thread and try out your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The class is not called `Date` but [DateTime](http://es.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [createFromFormat()](http://es.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method requires PHP/5.3 or greater. Whatever, the format you have is correctly recognised by the [constructor](http://es.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) so all you need is:

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('2011-10-31T16:22:00');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: I know understand the problem... I am falling behind with my php version as I am using 5.2.16.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use substr to extract, or simply use strtotime. I have used both and they are both useful solutions. strtotime would be better if you also would need to extract the timestamp.